# In Github, how do I commit my changes to a clone and submit a pull request?

Tags: github, clone, fork

I cloned a Github repo, made some changes, now I need to commit them and send a pull request. How do I turn my clone into a fork?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to the github repo, then click "fork". Now you have a fork :) Now you need to push your changes to your fork and send the pull request via github

```
git remote add myfork git@github.com:MyUsername/MyForkRepository.git
git push myfork master
```

From there you can send the pull request very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [github's hub](https://github.com/github/hub), all on the command line. For the ultimate win you can change 'origin' to be your fork, and change the project you forked to upstream with some renames:

```
# fork the project you cloned, creates a new remote with your username
# (and forks the project on github if you haven't already done so):
git fork
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote rename YOURUSERNAME origin
```